# Add documentID of fetched document to array in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that "Joins" data from a list of documents in a collection.
I then return the result as an array, but I want to return the documentId as well (doc.id) in the list that i return.

How can i do that?

```
    const restData = [];
    
    //const userId = ctx.auth.uid;
    const userId = 'dHAP1CNN6LhJWddQoTqyIkqIjhB2'; // !!! TEST ONLY
    const all = await db.collection(`/customers/${userId}/lunch_cards`).listDocuments().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const nextData = db.collection(`/restaurants`).doc(doc.id).get();
            const newData = {...nextData, documentId: doc.id}; <-- This does not work only documentId isout in newData
            console.log(util.inspect(newData));
            restData.push(nextData);
            console.log(doc.id);
        });
    });

    const snaps = await Promise.all(restData);
    const responseArray = snaps.map((s) => {return s.data()});

    return responseArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

Solution:

Just adding a new string to the array :)

```
const responseArray = snaps.map((s) => {
        const snapData = s.data();
        if (snapData) {
            snapData['id'] = s.id;
        }
        return snapData;
    });
```